# Date Flip Function in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting date in this format through soap api oracle service cloud

**2016-03-08T06:20:16Z**

How can I flip it through a function in VB?

Comment: What do you mean by "flip it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Function DateFlip(D As String)
        Try
            Dim result As String() = D.Split(New String() {"-", "T", "Z", ":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim test As Integer = CInt(result(3))
            If (test > 12) Then
                Return result(2) + "/" + result(1) + "/" + result(0) + " " + result(3) + ":" + result(4) + ":" + result(5) + " PM"
            Else
                Return result(2) + "/" + result(1) + "/" + result(0) + " " + result(3) + ":" + result(4) + ":" + result(5) + " AM"

            End If

        Catch e As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try
```

Add this function to your VB class

```
DateFlip("2016-03-08T06:20:16Z")
```

Answer (score -1):

i know it is already answered but i have better code in one line try mine too

```
 Dim time As String = "2016-03-08T06:20:16Z"
 MsgBox(CDate(time.Substring(0, 10)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +
 " " +
 CDate(time.Substring(11, 8)).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"))
```